# add and remove list sections using binding value in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I try to add and remove sections in the list by using binding value, so when add or remove items form the "listSectins" that will add and remove sections in the list.

```
   @State private var listSectins = ["SectionOne", "SectionTwo"]
    
     var body: some View {
            
            NavigationView {
                    List(selection: $selection) {
                            Section {
                            ForEach(self.firstSectionData) { rowData in
                                MainMenuRowView(rowData: rowData)
                            }
                            .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                                self.groupData.rowsGroup[0].move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                            })
                        }
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you show your demo code? It is not clear what activates binding and what is going to be inside sections, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try the code bellow and its work

```
 List(selection: $selection) {
            if self.isEditMode {
                Section {
                    ForEach(self.firstSectionData) { rowData in
                        MainMenuRowView(rowData: rowData, isEditMode: self.isEditMode)
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                        self.groupData.rowsGroup[0].move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                    })
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
            }
```